# WCF gzip compression?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, compression, gzip, discountasp

I need to compress my WCF response. 
After few google search, I found that

- I need to enable compression on iis7
- I need to add some entry in the applicationhost.config.

My wcf is hosted on discountasp.net. In the control panel, I didn't find any option to enable compression.
And also, the applicationhost.config is located in the 'C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config' directory.

And in the shared hosting environment, I dont have access to this directory.

My question is, if my above observation is correct, how do I get it done in the shared hosting??

### edit:

I have found something here:
[enter link description here](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1973/asp-net-enable-gzip-compression-via-web-config)

I tried this with no luck. In the response header in Fiddler, I dont see any compression.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to implement an HttpModule that would intercept the response based on the content type and compress the output on the fly, using the GZipStream class.

[This post](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/09/15/Compress-Asp.net-Ajax-Web-Service-Response---Save-Bandwidth.aspx) has a complete example and I've used this method successfully in production. All you need to do is change your Web.config to register the http module:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add name="JsonCompressionModule" type="JsonCompressionModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

The example does it for JSON responses but there's nothing that stops you from doing the same thing for XML responses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. if I add the <httpmodules> in my web.config, I get error. HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error

An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

Comment: Hi, have you solve your issue? Please try to change your application pool to classic mode. If it doesnt solve your issue, please try to contact their support team. :)